# Not algebraic extension inside a affine algebra which is not a domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

It is known that if a field $K$ is a $k$-algebra, and there is a finitely generated domain (affine domain) $B$ such that $K\subseteq B$, then $K$ must be algebraic over $k$ (a particular case happens when $K=B$). Can this happens when $B$ is finitely generated algebra but not a domain? If not, what would be an example of this, i.e., can there be a field $K$ embedded in an affine algebra which is NOT a domain?

Comment: Yeah, just edited, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is an affine $k$-algebra containing $K$, just take any prime ideal $P\subset B$ and consider $B'=B/P$.  Since $K$ is a field, $K$ still embeds in $B'$, and $B'$ is a domain.

(By the way, I don't know of any proof of the result that is made easier by assuming that $B$ is a domain.  The proof I know of is to take a maximal ideal $M\subset B$ and consider the quotient $L=B/M$.  By the Nullstellensatz, $L$ is algebraic over $k$, and hence $K$ is also algebraic since it embeds in $L$.)

Comment: In Kemper's Book, A Course in Commutative Algebra, they will prove the Nullstellensatz using the fact mentioned. There is a proof for the proposition which uses the fact that is a domain to work on the quotient field. See Proposition 1.1. for a reference.

Comment: Your answer uses the fact that you can take that algebra $B$. Part of my question is when does an extension exists, (for examples, can you construct a finitely generated algebra containing $k(x)$? An in your example the algebra is a domain. I want the extension $B$ to not be a domain.

Comment: I'm not assuming $B$ is a domain.  I'm showing that if any such $B$ exists, then there exists another $B'$ which is a domain.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! I got it!